# Subtraction in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert, database-trigger

I am trying to create this trigger that allows me to subtract from the quantity present in articles, the quantity of articles that have just been sold. The only thing that doesn't work is subtraction. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

```
CREATE TRIGGER subtraction
AFTER INSERT ON SoldItems
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE s INT(11);
DECLARE qta INT(11);
SELECT Quantity INTO s
FROM Articles
WHERE ID=NEW.IDArticle
SET s=s-NEW.Quantity
UPDATE Articles SET Quanty= s WHERE ID=NEW.IDArticle
END
```

Comment: This would set the value to `0`.  That doesn't seem useful.  Sample data and desired results would help -- as would a database tag.

Comment: I just have to do a subtraction, but not as well as in SQL.
I have to subtract from a variable 'declared at the beginning of the Trigger (containing the quantity of a specific article in the Articles table) the NEW quantity that I am inserting in SoldItems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to `select`, compute, then `update`. You could use a simple `update` statement directly in the trigger, like so:

```
delimiter //

create trigger subtraction
after insert on solditems
for each row
begin
    update articles 
    set quantity = quantity - new.quantity 
    where id = new.id_article;
end
//

delimiter ;
```